# Spring Cloud gateway do not validate token for PermitAll URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway, where I have ignored a set of URLs and authenticate a set of  Authorized URLs.  I have added `SecurityContextRepository` and `AuthenticationManager` which validates the token, now the issue is because it checks the token for every coming request so in case if I have an expired token coming in the header for an open endpoint it gives me an error that the token is expired.
Which I do not want because I have kept the endpoint open.
How can I resolved this, Does adding `addFilterBefore` or `addFilterafter` would work?
Please suggest something for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the request come from? If the token is not valid you should not send it in the request, because the `SecurityFilterChain` will detect the token and try to authenticate you, even if you have `permitAll` on the URL.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio The request coming from the front end, as I am setting the token in local storage so that will gets added in the subsequent request, so post-login I am hitting an open endpoint with the token.